# Upgrade to TLSV1.0 or 1.1 to TLSV1.2 in android using httpclient

Tags: android, httpclient, tls1.2

My application existing running tlsv1.0 or 1.1 and want to update tls version 1.2, but still showing old version tls1.0 or tls1.1 not showing 1.2. Sample code:

```
public class TLSSocketFactoryNew extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

    public TLSSocketFactoryNew() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        TrustManager[] managers = new TrustManager[] { new TrustManagerManipulator() };
        context.init(null, managers, new SecureRandom());
        internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();

    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    /*
     * Utility methods
     */

    private static Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
        if (socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)
                && isTLSServerEnabled((SSLSocket) socket)) { // skip the fix if server doesn't provide there TLS version
            ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.2"});
        }
        return socket;
    }

    private static boolean isTLSServerEnabled(SSLSocket sslSocket) {
        System.out.println("isTLSServerEnabled :: " + sslSocket.getSupportedProtocols().toString());
        for (String protocol : sslSocket.getSupportedProtocols()) {
            if (protocol.equals("TLSv1.1") || protocol.equals("TLSv1.2")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My concern now is, I just want to make support my app only tlsv1.2 version, all the old version should be avoided.

How I made the call **TLSSocketFactoryNew** in my utility class, using only **httpclient**- don't need solution about **okhttp**, **httpurlconnection**.

*Util.java*

```
HttpClient mHttpClient= returnHttpClient(httpParams);
```

and getting httpclient

```
private HttpClient returnHttpClient(HttpParams httpParams) {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    try {
      registry.register(new Scheme("https", (SocketFactory) new TLSSocketFactoryNew(), 443));
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParams, registry),httpParams);
    return  client;
  }
```

I added this snip on inside oncreate on Activity,

```
try {
            ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getBaseContext());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.1'
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/core-1.51.0.0.jar')
//  compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.7.2.jar')
compile files('libs/jsonic-1.3.0.jar')
```

I raise point here, where I am wrong to upgrade my tls version up to v1.2, am I missing something in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this will gonna help for you, Exactly same issue, I solved by below snips:

Just Get the HttpClient:

```
private HttpClient getHttpClient(HttpParams httpParams) {
    SSLContext sslContext = null;
 try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(null, null, null);
        SSLSocketFactory delegate = null;
        delegate = new TLSSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(delegate);
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
       return httpclient;
 } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
 } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
 }
}
```

and TLSSocketFactory.java file should be

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    private static final String[] TLS_V12_ONLY = {"TLSv1.2"};

    final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

    public TLSSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory base) {
        this.delegate = base;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private Socket patch(Socket s) {
        if (s instanceof SSLSocket) {
            ((SSLSocket) s).setEnabledProtocols(TLS_V12_ONLY);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

if you want more learn please go following links:

https://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/

https://medium.com/tech-quizlet/working-with-tls-1-2-on-android-4-4-and-lower-f4f5205629a

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that whatever machine you are running this on has TLS 1.2 enabled.

Set the SSLContext:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create().useProtocol("TLSv1.2").build();
```

Then build your HttpClient with the HttpClientBuilder:

```
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
builder.setSSLContext(sslContext);
```

Comment: You need to provide more information on what 'is not working'. Please provide the code and the error you are getting

Comment: App is working perfectly fine but on wireshark it is showing TLSv1.0 instead of TLSV1.2. I am not getting any error, app working fine only problem is not getting expected tls version which is 1.2. I tried couple of ways include code here: https://defuse.ca/b/63tB7tCb, Thanks

Comment: In a few areas you have this line:
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
Update them all to sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

Comment: even I try to update all TLSv1.2 but its not getting 1.2. Don't know, what's going on?

Comment: Just noticed in the code you show on defuse.ca/b/63tB7tCb it does not mention anywhere setEnabledProtocols. But your code in the post shows that you do have it?

Comment: I did that on TLSSocketFactory,  https://defuse.ca/b/HauX8Ukuo8ePkuOnS3OoNh and above link is just try to get httpclient return.