# How to enable and use TLSv1.0 from Android?

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

I am writing an app which should perform some HTTP requests to a server. This server unfortunately supports only TLSv1.0 or SSLv3.

I tried to create custom SSLSocketFactory like suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143155/upgrade-to-tlsv1-0-or-1-1-to-tlsv1-2-in-android-using-httpclient/55580921#55580921) answer, but it seems that TLSv1.0 is simply unsupported by the platform, while using TLSv1.1 or higher causes to Handshake error.

But at the same time, I am able to connect to the destination server from the browser in the emulator, so it should be possible overall.

```
        client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .sslSocketFactory(TLSSocketFactory(sslContext.socketFactory), trustManager)
        .build()
```

Where TLSSocketFactory is a custom class with only TLSv1.0 enabled. I am getting Handshake failed or unsupported protocol error message.

Is it possible to enable TLSv1.0 and how to?

Comment: "I am able to connect to the destination server from the browser" -- if you mean Chrome, I expect that it has its own SSL/TLS stack and is not using the platform's. I don't know about your `TLSSocketFactory` implementation, but have you tried [`COMPATIBLE_TLS`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/https/)? TLSv1.0 [should be in there, at least for a bit](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4499).

Comment: Yes, I have tried COMPATIBLE_TLS, but according to link you provided, I need to provide custom connectionSpecs

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Barely any server supports this cipher anymore; it's BROKEN (this means, that plain-text communication would be about as secure as that).

Comment:  Fix  the  server 

Comment: I can't control the server guys, I just need the job to be done :)

Answer (score 1):

If it really has to be, you would need to down-grade `OkHttp` version to [`3.x`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/TlsVersion.html), which still supports it.

The proper fix would rather be, to update the available ciphers on the server-side, in order to replace TLS 1.0 with modern ciphers. Only because it is possible to use it, does not imply that it would make sense; TLS 1.0 only provides imaginary security, which is a dangerous thing.